# Следует ли переводить вопросы, которые задали на других языках?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, перевод-содержимого

[Этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/442437/176684) был задан на английском языке, и поэтому 4 человека проголосовали за его закрытие.

После того, [Nicholas Chabanovsky отредактировал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/442437/revisions) — перевел с английского на русский.

Потом я тоже голосовал за закрытие этого вопроса, но по другой причине. Для меня это было немного неловко: там 4 голоса связанные со старой версией, а я как-то один решил закрыть новую версию.

- Что я должен был делать в такой ситуации?
- Следует ли переводить вопросы, которые задали на других языках?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Такие вопросы следует отмечать тревогой, как требующие внимания модератора, а затем закрывать. В дальнейшем, модератор перенесет вопрос в англоязычное сообщество.

Это связано с двумя причинами.

1. К сожалению, если перевести вопрос и дать ответ, то автор продолжит общение на английском языке (вывод из практики). То есть а) автор прекрасно осознает то, что он находится в русскоязычном сообществе, б) автор прекрасно знает русский язык (так как понял ответ и комментарии).
2. Возможность переносить вопросы между сообществами, насколько я могу судить, есть далеко не у всех. У модераторов она точно есть.

---

К сожалению, я поступил неправильно в упомянутом вами вопросе. Причина - вопрос был низкого качества - затраты на перевод и редактирование были одинаковые. Скорее всего, надо было отредактировать и перенести.

Comment: Ответ устарел - модераторы давно уже перестали переносить такие вопросы на en.so (насколько я понял, по просьбе участников en.so).

Comment: @PavelMayorov Модераторы не переносят только слабые вопросы, на сколько я знаю.

Answer (score 5):

### Ручной способ.

Оставить сообщение следующего содержания и ждать ответа.

> Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As follows from the name, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or `[ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)`. This question may get closed soon, but if you choose to translate, it will surely be reopened, once the translation is done.

### Технический способ (через доработку движка сайта)

Думаю, пользователю помогла бы следующая возможность.

1. Такой вопрос закрывается с формулировкой [не по теме] — [несоответствующий язык]. ([off-topic] — [wrong language])
2. Когда автор заходит на страницу своего вопроса, он видит уведомление о закрытии на двух языках: местном и универсальном английском (либо его языке, если можно распознать)
3. Автору предлагается выбор из двух вариантов:

   1. Перевести вопрос на язык, соответствующий тому разделу SO, где он задал вопрос.
   2. Переместить вопрос на соответствующий языку раздел SO. Здесь должен быть список, желательно с включением бета-сайтов. Название каждого локального SO на его родном языке, как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если автор выбрал редактирование вопроса, то он попадает в очередь проверок на переоткрытие и благополучно открывается.

Если автор выбрал перенос, то вопрос появляется как новый, открытый, с нулевым рейтингом на новом сайте.

Comment: Может быть, добавить причину закрытия? Дополнительно к «нужно перенести на другой сайт/на Мету».

Comment: For программистов? lol