# Отношение сообщества к вопросам, которые публикуются с целью дать ответ?

Tags: обсуждение

Я так понимаю, сообщество лояльно к таким вопросам?

Речь не идет о вопросах "помогите, как сделать", "что я делаю не так", "где ошибка", и так далее...

Допустим, пользователь знает ответ на какой-то вопрос, публикует вопрос, и отвечает на него. Это же допустимо, да. Вопрос в другом: а как много можно таких вопросов задавать?

Comment: Вроде никаких формальных ограничений нет (главное не надоесть всем читателям, а то заминусуют -))

Comment: Эм.. Вообще-то наоборот приветствуется.

Comment: @avp насколько я знаю, минусы ставят за какой-нибудь детский сад, а не за вопрос/ответ. Или у вас тут своя атмосфера?))

Comment: И ещё связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1051/178988

Comment: avp имел в виду множество однотипных малополезных вопросов-ответов, более спамовидных нежели полезных. В ином случае, неважно от одного ли участника пришла сотня вопросов или от сотни по одному. То что вы дадите на них ответы - тоже не важно. Если кого-то ответ не удовлетворит, он даст свой)

Comment: @misdeed, минусуют то, что не нравится, а плюсуют -- что нравится. Очевидно, если кому-то (неважно почему) ваши самоответы не понравятся, то он будет ставить минусы.

Comment: @Bharata нет, модераторы не управляют Духом. А кто тут бот, я не понял?

Comment: простое правило: полезность вопросов/ответов не зависит от того кто автор, а определяется их содержимым. Чем больше востребованных вопросов и подходящих ответов опубликовано, тем лучше¶ И не слушайте "нравится/не нравится" рассуждения — есть действия, которые помогают сайту (голосование один из полезных сигналов—читайте подсказки), а есть случаи когда злоупотребляют функциональностью сайта (часть голосов может автоматически откатываться). Явного тролля, который к примеру, по системе Морзе голосует по своему желанию или забанят или ему это надоест рано или поздно.