# Стоит ли переводить вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, перевод-содержимого

С одной стороны это хорошо — вопрос не закроют, а если он качественный, то на него ответят (скорее всего).
С другой стороны автор может не знать русского и ему ответы просто будут не понятны.

Comment: @Suvitruf Может стоило бы ещё раз обсудить? К данному  вопросу собственно более подходит дубликат по первй ссылке. Под ответом от Николая есть комментарий, который сеет сомнение в его актуальности. Ответ на этот комментарий с не совсем уверенной формулировкой: "на сколько я знаю".

Comment: @0xdb может и стоит. Хуже от этого не будет.

Comment: Связанное: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8092/15479), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342/15479), [три](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1051/15479).

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, может задупликатишь?

Comment: @Grundy я уже переоткрыл.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, а зачем? :-) вроде 100% дубликат, в чем смысл оставлять?

Comment: @Grundy чтоб обсудить. Может мнение изменилось. Мы так часто делаем.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, с этой стороны вряд ли что-то может измениться. Даже целая причина для закрытия есть. Оставлять полную копию предыдущих вопросов нет смысла ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Андрей преоткрыл после моего комментария. Что в нём не так?

Comment: @0xdb, после того вопроса был вопрос, в котором модераторы с enso просили не переносить к ним и решили просто добавить специальную причину закрытия. После этого ничего не менялось - все вопросы не на русском языке нужно закрывать с этой причиной

Comment: @Grundy  _после того вопроса был вопрос_ - всё правильно,  если был другой вопрос и другое решение, то надо чтобы их легко можно было найти. Поэтому и переоткрыли.

Comment: @0xdb не вижу связи, честно говоря :) [Вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4039/186999)