Можно ли переводить вопрос/ответ на основном сайте?
На Мете мы часто переводим текст (чаще всего с английского) вопросов/ответов, к примеру, если получили от сотрудников. Но на основном сайте придерживаемся правила, что мы не можем менять "смысл" сообщения, так как только автор вправе менять сам текст.
С одной стороны, такое действие "помогает" контенту, но с другой стороны "перевод" может исказить первоначальный смысл, с чем "автор" может не согласиться (?)
Как поступать?

Можно ли "переводить" на основном сайте (с английского, или любых других языков, с целью "помочь") текст таких вопросов/ответов?
a) Можно ли принимать такого рода правки?


конечно же, в свободное время, после "основных" более важных правок.

обращаясь к сообществу, прошупроголосовать за два данных ответа, которые гласят разную точку зрения. Количеством голосов, будет ясно мнение большинства.

Перепечатывание кода с картинки может нарушить лицензию, под которой издан код. Поэтому все вставки кода автора должны быть на совести автора. Будьте осторожнее с этим, не смешивайте с другими редактированиями обычного текста этот нюанс.

@aepot, может нарушить лицензию, под которой издан код => речь о стороннем источнике, или же переписывание с ide ТС к примеру. И если можно по переводу тоже ответьте ваше мнение. Я уберу эту часть тогда из вопроса, чтоб не было два вопроса

Неважно в каком источнике, я не юрист, а просто предостерегаю от неосторожных действий. Конечно, если вы готовы выигрывать суды например у работодателя автора за публикацию кода под лицензией Creative Commons на SO без разрешения владельца кода, можете свободно копировать чужой код откуда угодно.

я никогда не копирую код, а если беру из ответов, пишу первоисточник. Речь идет о вопросах, где к примеру сам ТС вставил свой код картинкой... за незнанием как использовать ru.SO

Ещё раз, все такие манипуляции с чужим кодом на ваш страх и риск. Если считаете, что это не будет иметь последствий, команда SO с удовольствием переведёт стрелки на вас, если на них подадут в суд. Будете рядом например с автором сидеть в суде на соседних креслах. Вы же не знаете, что там автор нарушил публикуя этот код, верно? Хотите поделить с ним ответственность - пожалуйста, никто не против. Допустим ваш адвокат вас отмажет грамотно, но оно вообще надо?

@aepot, а разве он не нарушает показывая ТОТ же самый код картинкой? // У меня есть код-и вставляет картинку...мы просто улучшаем видимость, показывая ему пример (он/ему=ТС)

Откуда мне знать, я не юрист. К тому же лицензии разные бывают и ответственность разную предусматривают.

Не согласиться еще как может, но большая проблема это то, что задавший вопрос на иностранном языке может быть вообще не понимает русский. Соответственно, даже если вы ему переведете вопрос, ответы будут для него бесполезны. Если же понимает, но "перепутал сайт", сможет и без посторонней помощи перевести. Так что я считаю, как минимум вопросы не стоит переводить (ответы - может быть, если они полезные).

Кстати есть дубликат, но какой-то слишком древний: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1051/240512

@MSDN.WhiteKnight, благодарю за вопрос-дубликат, там есть интересные для меня моменты +полезно было.

Если автор выбрал редактирование вопроса, то он попадает в очередь проверок на переоткрытие и благополучно открывается.
Если автор выбрал перенос, то вопрос появляется как новый, открытый, с нулевым рейтингом на новом сайте.
...жалко, что сейчас такой практики нету


С одной стороны, такое действие "помогает" контенту, но с другой
стороны "перевод" может исказить первоначальный смысл, с чем "автор"
может не согласиться (?)

Я не думаю, что на ruSO сидит много лингвистов, которым абсолютно нечего делать, кроме как переводить вопросы с одного языка на другой. Поэтому большая часть (если не все) переводов сведётся к машинному, что ухудшит качество контента, исказит смысл и т.д.
В первую очередь, мы должны поддерживать определённый уровень качества на платформе. Это позволит сосредоточить усилия на создании и улучшении контента, который уже написан на русском языке, что соответствует цели ruSO как русскоязычного сообщества.
В связи с этим должен быть единый подход для всех — закрывать/отклонять.
P.S. Улучшать или править стоит только те вопросы, которые написаны на великом, могучем, правдивом и свободном русском языке 

я не русская, никогда в жизни не была ни в одной точке России (хотя знаю что посещу её), знаю больше четырех языков, на одном из которых постоянно говорю/пишу документацию/шучу/пою/а иногда и думаю без переводчика. Если у меня есть свободное время, и я могу помочь переведя текст, исключения входят в норму?

@Dev18 если есть свободное время, то лучше сосредоточиться на тех вопросах которые уже на русском языке. Великое множество ответов и вопросов нуждается в правках сообщества. А если есть возможность что-то перевести, то лучше найдите на enSO интересные вопросы с качественными ответами и локализуйте у нас на ruSO с указанием ссылки на оригинал. Поймите простую вещь, нет смысла переводить всякую глупость (ни автору, ни сообществу от этого пользы не будет).

английским я не владею должным образом (перевод с en.SO) // переводить всякую глупость => почему глупость, тело вопроса с другого языка, либо старый ответ на другом языке. // ни автору, ни сообществу от этого пользы не будет => если вопрос/ответ интересный сообществу будет плюс к базе, а автору будет протянута рука и возможно это сыграет ключевую роль в решении его задачи, но за незнанием языка он испытывает сложности. Великое множество ответов и вопросов нуждается в правках сообщества => согласна, но если вам случайно встретился такой случай и уже вы на странице вопроса/ответа

Я изменила вопрос, обратите пожалуйста внимание - я использую можно ли, вместо нужно ли

@Dev18 вам конечно никто не запрещает переводить, так что если очень хочется - дерзайте. Но ещё раз повторюсь, лично Я считаю это не целесообразным и в общем случае будет единственным верным решением такую правку не одобрять, а сам вопрос поставить на закрытие.

@Dev18, тут я разделяю точку зрения @Amgarak: при переводе больше вероятность того, что изначальный замысел автора исказится (вспомните мои правки))), там даже и без перевода иногда такое происходило ‍♂️ (стараюсь так больше не делать)). Одно дело правщик — лингвист, но какой прецедент это создаст для других? Зачастую вижу, что вопрос на английском на ruSo задают русские пользователи. Что же, если они не переводят вопрос, нам это делать за них? Пускай если им нужно решение их проблемы, то соблюдают правила. Закрытие вопроса по такой причине считаю как полезное нравоучение.

@Chaos_Sower даже если мы представим, что вопрос задал англоговорящий пользователь (ошибся SO к примеру) которому мы перевели вопрос. Допустим нам надо что-то уточнить? И тут первая проблема, он нам ответит на английском... если вообще поймёт и ответит. Следом прилетает от кого-то ответ с пояснениями на русском, англоговорящий товарищ что-то на английском начнёт уточнять и это всё скатится в жуткое болото и тотальное непонимание. Отсюда уже складывается ни одна и не две проблемы, а целый вагон... что по итогу приведёт к замусированию контента и снижению его качества.

Можно, но не нужно. Это задача и прямой интерес для автора вопроса.

и вопросы и ответы? вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1574160/revisions -ваши действия (автор был более месяца назад)

@Dev18 конкретно от этого примера, если его удалить - сообщество не обеднеет.

@Dev18, в вашем примере всего 4 слова, которые понимает каждый программист)) Так что и искажения априори не может быть — такой мини-перевод, как по мне, можно осуществить (но только в качестве исключения, именно такие)

@Chaos_Sower, на самом деле, я даже не ожидала, что получу такой фидбек от сообщества. Столько мнений, за что конечно огромное спасибо. Тема разжевана, почти все случаи рассмотрены. Остаётся как бы "крайний случай", то есть сие действие не запрещено, но лучше подумать прежде чем переводить по каждому конкретному случаю.

Нужно переводить и нужно принимать.

Я тоже так думаю!!!

А почему нужно? Быть может более развёрнуто объясните?
